# Countifs Indirect with Column increment

Tags: excel

I'm working on a workbook, containing 33 sheets, 31 sheets for daily tasks.

I wanted to show daily productivity in about 15 columns each day,I used Indirect with countifs but when I copy formula to next 15th cell it never goes to the right reference ..

```
=(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&SL$6&"'!J:J"),"B2",INDIRECT("'"&$SL6&"'!$L:$L"),$C7))
```

This formula counts In specific day (sheet) in J:J "Paid"("B2") while also it counts the person who sold items "Name"("C7")

this formula works perfect but...

in SL6 my sheet reference lays, for example, SL6:Sheet1 SM6:Sheet2

I want this formula in next 15th cell while it goes toTA6 which is Sheet16's reference, it should go to SM6, I know if I drag this formula into very next cell it will produce the right result but my formula will be staying every 15th cell till 31 sheets.. please I avoid VBA

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  When I select the cell containing your formula and fill right, it changes the reference for the sheet to SM6, then SN6, etc. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: You have one `SL$6` and one `$SL6`. The first will increment by column (SL, SM, etc) if filled right; the second will increment the row (6, 7, etc) if filled down. Also, you have `"B2"` quoted which means that the COUNTIFS is looking for the *literal* string value *B2*. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I wrote there, If I add this formula to say something like AJ6, while I will have same formula in AY6, now here is the problem, when copied to AY6, formula increments to TA6 where cell reference goes to Sheet 16, while I need it to go to SM6 and so on. Hope that you'll understand now